# How to present data in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to present data in a format like this in python using a dictionary. Below is a sample.
How can I create this in python. The values of each field will come from data within a webservice. You can see some nesting is going on.

```
        contactDetails: {
                    emailAddress: payload.EmailAddress,
                    name: {
                        familyName: payload.FamilyName,
                        givenName: payload.GivenName,
                        middleName: payload.MiddleName
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'll need to use `str` as the dict keys:

```
contactDetails = {
    "emailAddress": payload.EmailAddress,
    "name": {
        "familyName": payload.FamilyName,
        "givenName": payload.GivenName,
        "middleName": payload.MiddleName
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how do I write the code in python to generate that format.

Comment: response_body = {}

Comment: I don't understand. That's the code. Don't you already have `payload`? How does `payload` look like?

Comment: I want to write code to generate that output and yes I have payload data coming from a webservice

Comment: That's the code! If you have the `payload` and it has `EmailAddress` etc. then that code GIVES you the data in the format you want.